# Why is my C++ program always throwing exception even if the user's input is ok?

Tags: c++, exception

What am I trying to achieve?

My goal is to make a program which will throw an exception and end the program everytime when input of type `char` is not either `a`, `b` or `c` and it should give following exception message: `"You can't enter nothing else except a,b,c".`

Where am I stuck at?

Even though user's input is `a`, `b` or `c` exception is being thrown.

Now my question is what should I do when if I enter a,b,c program keeps working and doesn't throw that exception?
Code:

```
int pitanjca()
  {
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<ime11<<" i  "<<ime22<<" sada započinjemo igru."<<endl;
    //Another question:
    cout<<"Pocinjemo sa pitanjima: "<<endl;
    cout<<"1.Kada je rođen Josip Broz Tito?";
    cout<<"a)7 maja 1892."<<endl;
    cout<<"b)25 maja 1892."<<endl;
    cout<<"c)25 maja 1900."<<endl;
    cout<<"Unesite odgovor: ";
    cin>>odgovor1;
    if(odgovor1!='a' || odgovor1!='b' || odgovor1!='c')
    {
      throw "Ne mozete unijeti nista osim a,b ili c";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    if(odgovor1=='a')
    {
      bodovi+=5;
    }
    else
    {
      bodovi+=0;
    }
```

This is main function:

```
 pitanja p(ime1,ime2);
  cout<<"Prvi igra: "<<ime1<<endl;
  try{
  player1bodovi=p.pitanjca();
  }catch (const char* msg) {
     cerr << msg << endl;
     goto tt;
  }
```

And tt looks like this:

```
system("PAUSE")
return 0;
```

Comment: Any character is always different than `a` or different than `b`

Comment: The condition always evaluates to `true`. Use the logical AND operator `&&` instead.

Comment: So what should I do, my logic here doesn't work...
How can I check if input is not a or b or c?

Comment: @Ron Dude I love you hahaha... 
It works now :) 
How can I submit your answer as correct one ?

Comment: You named it right - not(a or b or c). You can write it this way or use de Morgan's law and write it as (not a) and (not b) and (not c)

Comment: Start with the plain english (or croation if you prefer) statement that you want to trigger your exception. "I want to trigger my exception if the entered letter is not a or b or c." That can be written in boolean as `!(a || b || c)` which can be converted via DeMorgan's Rule to `!a && !b && !c`. I personally prefer the former, since it's 3 operations (one NOT and two ORs) vs the latter, since it's 5 operations (3 NOTs and 2 ANDs).

Comment: Thank you guys on the help provided. Appriciate it! 
@JohnFilleau

Comment: @JohnFilleau The preference should be for readability. The compiler should generate the same assembly for both.

Comment: @cigien I forget that compilers are smarter than me often. I still prefer the former. But personal preferences may of course vary.

Comment: Careful with `goto` it can go wrong in many surprising ways and even if you do get it right, you'll find it almost impossible to convince other people. You are usually better off using conventional loops and functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (odgovor1 != 'a' || odgovor1 != 'b' || odgovor1 != 'c')
```

Those should be `&&` operators. Think of what happens when you enter `a`. You will get:

```
false || true || true
```

which is `true`. In fact, you'll get true for *every* character since a single character cannot ever be all of `a`, `b`, and `c` at the same time.

---

However, there's probably little need to *separate* the scoring logic from the validation logic, you could combine the two with something like:

```
switch (odgovor1) {
    case 'a': bodovi += 5; break;
    case 'b':
    case 'c': break;
    default : throw "Ne mozete unijeti nista osim a, b ili c";
}
```